# mysql 5.6 Unknown system variable 'optimizer_trace'

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to follow [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html) tutorial to trace optimizer that is used by mysql for certain query.
But when I do

```
SET optimizer_trace="enabled=on";
```

It said `ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'optimizer_trace'.`
When I check, the optimizer_trace table isn't in information_schema db.

I had build mysql from source version 5.6 because in that page stated:

"In MySQL 5.6, a new tracing capability was added to the MySQL optimizer. The interface is provided by a set of optimizer_trace_xxx system variables and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OPTIMIZER_TRACE table, but is subject to change."

So my quiestion is:
Is the OPTIMIZER_TRACE table had already been changed?
If it is, is there any substitution for this table?
Or maybe should I build another version?

Comment: Run the query `SELECT @@VERSION, @@VERSION_COMMENT;`

Comment: It turns out that I have 10.3.10-MariaDB-1, not MySQL. From this [page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-variable-differences-between-mariadb-103-and-mysql-57/) I know that mariadb doesn't have optimizer_trace as system variables. Thanks for the hint